# How can I count a value of table records, using session variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, backend

I have an SQL table with a column named 'status.' This column contains only two values: 'pending' or 'solved'.

| status |
| --- |
| pending |
| pending |
| solved |
| solved |
| pending |

I want to count 'pending' entries from the 'status' column using session["user"] with an SQL query. How can I do it??

I am expecting an output like:
Count of 'pending' = 7

Because I only want to count the 'pending' values in the 'status' column..

Comment: Do u count using by javascript, or linq? Can u give me more detail?

Comment: No, I want to count it using sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below sql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as pending_count
FROM your_table_name
WHERE status = 'pending'
AND user_id = your_session_user_id;
```

If it is not enough, can you give me more detail?

Comment: Thank you, sir, it worked perfectly, and I clearly understand the query as will.

Comment: I'm glad. In that case, would you mind accepting my request for the answer.

Comment: Please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if you found this helpful.

Comment: yeah sure, sorry I forgot back then.